Custom domain for VPC endpoint
I have a VPC endpoint which is created along with VPC endpoint service, which connects to NLB and then to EKS service. Now as I try to connect to service I use the DNS of VPC endpoint, what I want is to create a domain (which should be private) in place of it and use that instead.
I tried the private DNS of endpoint service, but the domain is not getting verified, so stuck there.
Can someone help me how can I proceed with this ?

Tried:
https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/vpc-private-dns-name-endpoint-service

For using Custom Domain for your VPC Endpoint, you will need go through domain verification which is where you are now facing issues. If you don't own a domain, you can't get pass this setup. Since you have mentioned that you are looking to have a private domain, you can do as below:

Create a Private Hosted Zone associated to the VPC with the domain name you prefer. If you have one private hosted zone already for this domain, use that to add a new record. If not, you can create a new one however additional checks will be needed as this could affect other users in the VPC trying to resolve DNS records of the Private Hosted Zone you are creating

Once Private Hosted Zone is ready, you are to add an Alias record pointing at this VPC endpoint. Eg: www.test.com to vpce-xxxxx-yyyyy.amazonaws.com. This will help to resolve the domain record of www.test.com to get the Ip address of your VPC Endpoints.


The above will help in taking care of DNS lookups for clients within the same VPC. Now comes the question of what are you hosting on EKS. If this is over a TLS connection, you will need to get respective certificate for the domain created and associated to the NLB (or to your EKS pods). For both, you will have to create a self-signed (or your org private CA signed) certificate. To use with NLB's listener, load it to ACM.

Hi, thanks for your ans. I feel i'm going in right direction, since I have created a private hosted zine using route 53 and created a TXT record in it, its just that it says domain verification as pending do you have any idea on how to resolve that ?

@PriyankaSharma Private Hosted Zone won't work with domain validation. That option is only for Publicly resolvable domains which is not in your case. As I have mentioned, you don't need to use the Custom DNS option of VPC Endpoint. Instead get the endpoint created without and then create a DNS record in your Private Hosted Zone pointing at the Endpoint (As Alias record)

Thank you. I created a CNAME and was able to have the same result as I do with VPC endpoint. Though I want to know more on the case where you mentioned TLS part, can you walk me through it ?

@PriyankaSharma Good to hear that the Private Hosted Zone and CNAME did the trick. For the TLS, it is all at the NLB which you have used to create the service endpoint. On the TLS listener on this NLB, you can refer any certificate matching your above domain. Since is a private only domain, you might not have a well-known CA issued cert. In such a case, you can create a self-signed cert and then host it on ACM. Refer: https://medium.com/@chamilad/adding-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate-to-aws-acm-88a123a04301 . This is only needed if you need your clients to communicate in an encrypted channel.

Also with self-signed certificates, your clients need to trust it which depends on specific clients. Skipping that part as it is not relevant to the ask here

Thank you for explaining this, I am confused in self signed part, I might be misunderstanding this, doesn't AWS provides us with certificates and we can use it as is ?

AWS will only provide certificate for domains that you can prove ownership. This is done either by email or DNS validation. In your setup, the domain you are using is private and only resolves within the VPC. This can't be used to get certificate from ACM. However, you can create certificate externally and then import to ACM to use with your NLB.
